# How to add the name, if tag is not available in the XML, while converting into the CSV using XSLT?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have 2 scenarios where I'm not able to move further when I have to process the XML and create the CSV using XSLT.
Input File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<families>
    <family id ="1">
        <type_client>
            <code>1</code>
            <code>2</code>
        </type_client>
        <family_client>
            <code>99</code>
            <code>98</code>
        </family_client>
    </family>
    <family id ="2">
        <type_client>
            <code>3</code>
            <code>4</code>
        </type_client>
        <family_client>
            <code>88</code>
            <code>89</code>
        </family_client>
    </family>
</families>
```

**Scenario 1**: While converting XML file to CSV, I have to add the tag name '**family_name**' whether the tag exists or not (i.e., if tag exists tag name should come otherwise custom-defined name should come). local-name() will give the name if the tag exists otherwise it will not give. How to add the tag name if the tag doesn't exist?

**Scenario 2**: `<type_client>` has repeated child tag i.e., `<code>99</code>` and `<code>98</code>` (From the example). I have to add as many records as this `<code>` tag appears i.e., from the example I have to add 2 records.
Expected output for both the scenarios:
**type_client.csv**

```
id,family_name,type_client
1,,1
1,,2
2,,3
2,,4
```

**family_client.csv**

```
id,family_name,family_client
1,,99
1,,98
2,,88
2,,89
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="families">
        <xsl:result-document href="type.txt">
            <xsl:value-of select="family[1]/@id/local-name(),family[1]/family_name/local-name(),family[1]/type_client/local-name()" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="family">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id,family_name,type_client/code" separator=","/>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the output I'm getting:

```
id,family_name,type_client
1,Husband's Family,1,2
2,Wife's Family,3,4
```

**Note**: Here `family_name` value is added manually to show how it should come if it has the data, else tag as name should come when the tag is not present, after reading the comments.

Expected output:

```
id,family_name,type_client
1,Husband's Family,1
1,Husband's Family,2
2,Wife's Family,3
2,Wife's Family,4
```

Comment: Do you have the XSLT that creates the wanted output if family_name exists? Please show the existing code. Also which XSLT version you use? How do run the XSLT, have you considered to run two separate XSLT transformations in a row where the first adds the `family_name` when/where needed and then the second outputs your CSV data? In XSLT 3 you can also do such things in one stylesheet using the `transform` function. Or use modes as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676882/multiple-rows-using-xslt/50677187#50677187 to separate transformation steps.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"><xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/><xsl:template match="families"><xsl:result-document href="type.txt"><xsl:value-of select="family[1]/@id/local-name(),family[1]/family_name/local-name(),family[1]/type_client/local-name()" separator=","/><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text><xsl:for-each select="family"><xsl:value-of select="@id,family_name,type_client/code" separator=","/><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each></xsl:result-document></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: id|family_name|type_client
1|Husband's Family|1|2
2|Wife's Family|3|4

Above is the output coming

Comment: Please edit your question to include your XSLT, as code is hard to read in comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a case of adding `family_name` if it doesn't exist. It is a case of ensuring a value is output in the CSV if it doesn't exist.

Instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="@id,family_name,type_client/code" separator=","/>
```

You could do this (where `||` is a concat operator)

```
<xsl:value-of select="@id,(family_name||''),type_client/code" separator=","/>
```

So `(family_name||'')` will return an empty string if `family_name` does not exist. If `family_name` does exist, then concatenating an empty string will not affect it.

The creation of the header row seems a bit over-complicated. Instead of doing this....

```
<xsl:value-of select="family[1]/@id/local-name(),family[1]/family_name/local-name(),family[1]/type_client/local-name()" separator=","/>
```

You can just do this, as there is no point using `local-name()` when you already know what the name is (as you have hard-coded it in the xpath expression)

```
<xsl:text>id,family_name,type_client</xsl:text>
```

For your scenario 2, the solution is to use `xsl:for-each` on `family/type_client/code` and not just family

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="families">
        <xsl:result-document href="type.txt">
            <xsl:text>id,family_name,type_client&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="family/type_client/code">
                <xsl:value-of select="../../@id,(../family_name||''),." separator=","/>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```